# Cannot install uWSGI on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4 (paths?)

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, installation, uwsgi

The big picture is that I want Ubuntu server with nginx, uWGI, and Python 3 (virtualenv) to start some project.

I did follow recommendation that can be found on various places. When trying to install uWSGI using the `sudo pip install uwsgi`, I do observe the following error:

```
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I did find the [J.F.Sebastian's comment][1] from September 2012 about the neccessity to `$ sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev` -- it was for Python 2.7. So, I did the similar for Python 3.4 (seems successfully). However, I still observer the error.

When trying to search for the `Python.h`, I can find:

```
$ locate Python.h
/usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h
```

What else should I set to make uWSGI installed? (I am rather new to Ubuntu Linux, even though I did work with Unix far in the middle age ;)

**Update:**

Following the jwalker's advice from the comment below, I did `pip install uwsgi` from within activated virtualenv and without `sudo`. But then the installer cannot create subdirectories (like `build`) in the venv directory. I tried to `chmod go+w` for the venv, but it did not help. I admit I know nothing about virtualenv and pip, and also my Unix knowledge is a bit rusty:

```
  ...
  File "/var/www/hec_project/hec_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 218, in build_location
    _make_build_dir(build_dir)
  File "/var/www/hec_project/hec_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1527, in _make_build_dir
    os.makedirs(build_dir)
  File "/var/www/hec_project/hec_venv/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/hec_project/hec_venv/build'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/hecadmin/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Did you run that pip command with a default Python (which is 2.7)?

Comment: @jwalker: I am not sure what situation do you mean. I did install `virtualenv` and Python 3.4 inside. Then I did `$ sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev`. I suspect that `sudo pip install uwsgi` should be called with some argument, but I did use only that command that may use the default Python 2 somehow. I am not good in `pip` and what it exactly does, and how the installed packages can be configured -- namely the uwsgi that calls `gcc`. I know how to program in C++, it is clear to me that I should set the correct include directory, but I do not know how in this case.

Comment: First of all, if you're installing uWSGI into a virtualenv, don't `sudo`, activate the venv and then just `pip`. Now I'm not sure what went wrong for you, but this worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04: `sudo apt-get install python3`, `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, `virtualenv -p python3 venv`, `source venv/bin/activate`, `pip install uwsgi`.

Comment: your virtualenv is broken.  You should be able to create subdirectories. Recreate venv. Run the commands from @jwalker's comment using the same user.

Comment: @jwalker Can you copy your advice as the answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I had to create the `venv` directory manually and give it the write access for group and others. Is it OK? Should I formulate another question for this?

Comment: @pepr Oh, I didn't realize that your original dir was write-protected. If it's not, you shouldn't use `sudo` for `virtualenv` and `pip`, as I said before (because it complicates permissions). But since it is, try sudoing both `virtualenv` and `pip` commands, and you can keep `activate` as is. To summarize, try: `sudo apt-get install python3`, `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, `sudo virtualenv -p python3 venv`, `source venv/bin/activate`, `sudo pip install uwsgi`.

Comment: @jwalker: I am not sure, but I think I did try `sudo` everything. The problem is that the installation runs the C/C++ compiler, and it seems that some part simply cannot get the write access this way.

Comment: @pepr I did make sure it runs fine on my 12.04. Perhaps your permissions on `/var` are different or, which is more likely, you ran pip without activating venv first.

Comment: @jwalker: Thanks a lot. Please, formulate the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @pepr Thanks! Sorry for taking so long with this simple problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Install Python 3 headers to build uWSGI from source:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Create a Python 3 virtualenv in a `venv` subdir of current dir (prepend the command with `sudo` if current dir is privileged):

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

Activate the venv to be the target for `pip` (`.` is a shortcut for `source`):

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

Finally, install uWSGI (again, `sudo` if in a privileged dir):

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Comment: I'm looking to do the same, but how do you then setup for multiple apps each in their own venv and individual uwsgi install (within the venv)?  Can these be integrated with upstart?  How are the uwsgi instances managed in this case?

Comment: @monkut Each venv will have an independent uwsgi executable. They can directly go to upstart or, better yet, to [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

Answer (score 6):

Have you installed the correct python plugin for uwsgi?

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/uwsgi-plugin-python3

Then in config (your .ini file) put **python3** as plugin instead of **python** like this:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins         = python3

# Rest of your configuration...
```