# getting an error when trying to run uwsgi: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.4m.so.1.0

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi, uwsgi

I've been runing `uwsgi` like so:

```
uwsgi --ini CMS_uwsgi.ini
```

and it used to work. However, I tried running `uwsgi` again after a couple weeks and I get this error now:

```
uwsgi: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.4m.so.1.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error now. It Might be because recently, I did

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to remove installed packages that used to be installed as dependencies but aren't any longer (as mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application).

I tried to find it by running:

```
find -name "libpython3.4m.so.1.0"
```

but it did not return anything. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

I am using Lubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. First, did

```
pip uninstall uwsgi
```

then tried installing it again:

```
pip install uwsgi
```

but it gave me the error:

```
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I google'd around and came across this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/182313/install-uwsgi-1-2-5-via-pip which mentioned to install

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

so I installed `python2.7-dev` and retried installed `uwsgi` but got the same error. Realized I was using `python3`, came across this post: [Cannot install uWSGI on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4 (paths?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822829/cannot-install-uwsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-python-3-4-paths) which mentions to do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

I did that and retried installing `uwsgi` and it worked fine again.

Comment: some times deactivate and again activate the virualenv after uninstalling and again installing uwsgi is work .

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to run uwsgi in a virtual environment. Then run the following

```
pip install python-pcre
```

Now, try running the wsgi. Hope this helps!