# Error in installing uwsgi on ubuntu with python 3.5 using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, uwsgi

Getting an error installing uwsgi on a Vagrant box running Ubuntu 12.04 with python 3.5 through pyenv. Using pip to install. -- `pip install uwsgi`

Already tried this through [Cannot install uWSGI on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4 (paths?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822829/cannot-install-uwsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-python-3-4-paths):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Still getting this error

```
Collecting uwsgi
Using cached uwsgi-2.0.14.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
Complete output from command /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/geolo/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ptvihmd2/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-eecicssg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/geolo/include/site/python3.5/uwsgi:
running install
using profile: buildconf/default.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
detected CPU cores: 4
configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY  -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.14\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="14" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_LIBXML2 -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
*** uWSGI compiling server core ***
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/utils.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/protocol.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/socket.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/logging.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/master.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/master_utils.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/emperor.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/notify.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/mule.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/subscription.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/stats.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/sendfile.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/async.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/master_checks.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/fifo.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/offload.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/io.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/static.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/websockets.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/spooler.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/snmp.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/exceptions.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/config.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/setup_utils.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/clock.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/init.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/buffer.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/reader.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/writer.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/alarm.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/cron.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/hooks.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/plugins.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/lock.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/cache.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/daemons.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/errors.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/hash.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/master_events.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/chunked.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/queue.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/event.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/signal.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/strings.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/progress.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/timebomb.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/ini.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/fsmon.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/mount.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/metrics.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/plugins_builder.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/sharedarea.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/rpc.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/gateway.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/loop.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/cookie.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/querystring.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/rb_timers.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/transformations.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/uwsgi.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] proto/base.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] proto/uwsgi.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] proto/http.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] proto/fastcgi.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] proto/scgi.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] proto/puwsgi.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] lib/linux_ns.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/zlib.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/regexp.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/routing.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/yaml.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/ssl.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/legion.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/xmlconf.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/dot_h.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/config_py.o
*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyutils.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyloader.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/gil.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/profiler.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/symimporter.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/tracebacker.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/raw.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/gevent/gevent.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/gevent/hooks.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/cache/cache.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/nagios/nagios.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/carbon/carbon.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/http/http.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/http/keepalive.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/http/https.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/http/spdy3.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/ugreen/ugreen.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_http/router_http.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/logfile/logfile.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_static/router_static.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_expires/expires.o
[thread 3][gcc -pthread] plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o
[thread 2][gcc -pthread] plugins/transformation_template/tt.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o
*** uWSGI linking ***
gcc -pthread -o /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/geolo/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o lib/linux_ns.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/ssl.o core/legion.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/ugreen/ugreen.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -rdynamic -ldl -lz -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpcre -luuid -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lxml2 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lrt -lm /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a -lutil -lcrypt
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a(pytime.o): In function `pymonotonic_new':
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/Python/pytime.c:609: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a(pytime.o): In function `pygettimeofday_new':
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/Python/pytime.c:466: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/Python/pytime.c:466: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/Python/pytime.c:480: undefined reference to `clock_getres'
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a(pytime.o): In function `pymonotonic_new':
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/Python/pytime.c:609: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/Python/pytime.c:622: undefined reference to `clock_getres'
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a(timemodule.o): In function `py_process_time':
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/./Modules/timemodule.c:974: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/./Modules/timemodule.c:980: undefined reference to `clock_getres'
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a(timemodule.o): In function `time_clock_getres':
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/./Modules/timemodule.c:205: undefined reference to `clock_getres'
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a(timemodule.o): In function `time_clock_gettime':
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/./Modules/timemodule.c:151: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a(timemodule.o): In function `time_clock_settime':
/tmp/python-build.20170228143302.5560/Python-3.5.0/./Modules/timemodule.c:182: undefined reference to `clock_settime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** error linking uWSGI ***

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/geolo/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ptvihmd2/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-eecicssg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/geolo/include/site/python3.5/uwsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ptvihmd2/uwsgi/
```

Comment: Have you also tried `apt-get install build-essential`?

Comment: Yup, tried that. The error still exists

Comment: I can't help with the `pip`-way solution, but you may think to `apt-get install uwsgi` system-wide, if you have no specific reasons against that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error building uwsgi with pip in virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876251/error-building-uwsgi-with-pip-in-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python3

(in case your setting isn't available) Export setting. To check if your setting is available, type `locale` before typing code below. LC_ALL setting can be changed depending on your setting which one isn't available

```
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Install and upgrade pip

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Install build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Install setup tools

```
sudo pip3 install -U pip setuptools
```

Install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Install python3-dev

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Install uwsgi

```
pip3 install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the profile override was set to false. This usually happens inside a virtualenv.

To fix it, use the following code:

```
 sudo CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip install uwsgi -Iv
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to SSL linking issue, 
In file uwsgiconfig.py add following lines

```
self.libs.append('-L/tmp/ssl_lib')
self.libs.append('-L/usr/local/lib')
```

before the line self.libs.append('-lssl')

Its solved my issue can install package

Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

The post that by Ashish Srivastava pointed me in the right direction.  Because I'm still on CENTOS7, I had to install openssl11, but the system doesn't use it by default.  Below is the modified command I used to install uWSGI in pip, referencing openssl11 installed by yum.

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/openssl11/openssl" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64/openssl11" UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip install uwsgi -Iv
```